# How to describe a reference cursor associated with dynamic SQL in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, cursor

This is my first (edited) stackoverflow question, so please bear with me.

In Oracle 11g, I have a need to describe/interrogate the underlying columns of a reference cursor returned from a procedure call **on another database over a dblink**, in which the actual SQL is not always "explicit", but sometimes dynamically generated.

For example:

```
declare
    v_ref_cur sys_refcursor;
    v_cur_num number;
    v_col_count number;
    v_col_table dbms_sql.desc_tab3;
begin
    myProc@myDblink(v_ref_cur, 'myvalue');
    v_cur_num := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(v_ref_cur);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns3(v_cur_num, v_col_count, v_col_table);
    ...
end
```

If myProc() on the other database has an "explicit" SQL statement like:

```
open cursor for select * from foo where bar = myParam;
```

The cursor conversion and description (still) work just fine - I can determine the column names, types, lengths, etc returned by the procedure.

BUT, if myProc() on the other database involves dynamic SQL, like:

```
v_sql := 'select * from foo where bar = ''' || myParam || '''';
open cursor for v_sql;
```

I get an ORA-01001 invalid cursor error when attempting to call dbms_sql.to_cursor_number().

Is there a way to convert/describe a reference cursor derived from dynamic SQL as called from a remote procedure?  If so, how?  If not, why not?

Thanks for any/all assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Using DBMS_SQL across a database link raises many different errors, at least some of which are Oracle bugs.  Those problems can be avoided by putting all of the logic in a function compiled on the remote server.  Then call that function remotely.

```
--Create and test a database link
create database link myself connect to <schema> identified by "<password>"
    using '<connect string or service name>';
select * from dual@myself;

--myProc
create procedure myProc(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor, p_value varchar2) is
begin
    --open p_cursor for select * from dual where dummy = p_value;
    open p_cursor for 'select * from dual where dummy = '''||p_value||'''';
end;
/

--Simple function that counts and displays the columns.  Expected value is 1.
create or replace function count_columns return number is
    v_ref_cur sys_refcursor;
    v_cur_num number;
    v_col_count number;
    v_col_table dbms_sql.desc_tab3;
begin
    --ORA-01001: invalid cursor
    --myProc@myself(v_ref_cur, 'myvalue');
    myProc(v_ref_cur, 'myvalue');
    --ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
    --v_cur_num := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number@myself(v_ref_cur);
    v_cur_num := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(v_ref_cur);
    --Compilation error: PLS-00306: 
    --    wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DESCRIBE_COLUMNS3'
    --dbms_sql.describe_columns3@myself(v_cur_num, v_col_count, v_col_table);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns3(v_cur_num, v_col_count, v_col_table);
    return v_col_count;
end;
/

begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Number of columns: '||count_columns@myself());
end;
/

Number of columns: 1
```

Comment: I forgot to state the degree of difficulty - the called procedure is remote, called over a dblink.  Sorry!

Comment: Ok, now I can reproduce the problem.  But I don't have time to investigate it right now.  My initial thoughts are that you may need to move all of the processing to the remote server.